# Is there any option to Start Profiler programatically from node.js?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am looking on implementing the performance analysis for the web page. I have gone through some of the tools available and found Dev tools will be helpful. Is there any REST API to trigger the profiler from node.js?

Comment: No, but there should be tools that implement devtools profiler functionality using the underlying [CDP commands](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Profiler).

Comment: Thanks, above link helps in understanding the CDP commands. Also, found this link which explains how to start and stop the profile.
https://nitayneeman.com/posts/getting-to-know-puppeteer-using-practical-examples/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, see documentation here: https://nodejs.org/api/inspector.html#inspector_cpu_profiler

```
const inspector = require('inspector');
const fs = require('fs');
const session = new inspector.Session();
session.connect();

session.post('Profiler.enable', () => {
  session.post('Profiler.start', () => {
    // Invoke business logic under measurement here...

    // some time later...
    session.post('Profiler.stop', (err, { profile }) => {
      // Write profile to disk, upload, etc.
      if (!err) {
        fs.writeFileSync('./profile.cpuprofile', JSON.stringify(profile));
      }
    });
  });
});
```